# Single product url gives 404 after magento upgrade

Tags: magento

I upgraded an Enterprise install from `v1.10.1.1` to `v1.12.0.2` and only one of the product url is giving a 404 error. Other product urls work fine, so its a bit odd.

From what I could gather as resolutions, I have tried the following:

- Refreshing the cache
- Deleting the whole var folder
- Recompiling everything
- Disable compilation
- Reindexed everything

And yet I don’t seem to figure out a way to make it work.

There is nothing in the log files, I am totally clueless on what it could be. Anything else that I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto Admin -> Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management

Check to make sure the product id exist

Comment: It wasn't there so I added it but still doesn't work after refreshing cache/compilation/indexes.

Comment: Try changing the url key in for that product in product admin. When you say indexes are you referring to the product flat table?

Comment: Did you add it with the same format as one of the other product that is working?

Comment: No, the index management of Magento. I added a new one, even tried editing an old url which works, but no gain, surprisingly the old one still works.

Comment: I removed garbage entries regarding that product, re-entered the url with the request path and the target path (`catalog/product/view/id/57`) and after reindexing + recompilation + refreshing cache, it started working! Thanks bro!

Answer (score 0):

Check `report_event_types` table if it's empty run this query that's all..

```
 INSERT INTO `report_event_types` (`event_type_id`, `event_name`, `customer_login`) VALUES
(1, 'catalog_product_view', 0),
(2, 'sendfriend_product', 0),
(3, 'catalog_product_compare_add_product', 0),
(4, 'checkout_cart_add_product', 0),
(5, 'wishlist_add_product', 0),
(6, 'wishlist_share', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you execute the following command then problem will be solved.

```
 INSERT INTO `report_event_types` (`event_type_id`, `event_name`, `customer_login`) VALUES
(1, 'catalog_product_view', 0),
(2, 'sendfriend_product', 0),
(3, 'catalog_product_compare_add_product', 0),
(4, 'checkout_cart_add_product', 0),
(5, 'wishlist_add_product', 0),
(6, 'wishlist_share', 0);
```